# Override authorization policy in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

**EDIT**: This has been solved. Please see my EDIT below. For a more "default" solution where you do not need a "ignore the claim completely" override, see the accepted answer. At the time of writing, My EDIT below contains code that helps you support another scenario where you want to completely ignore the requirement instead of override it.

I have seen multiple posts on this issue but none really solve my problem.
[One promising one](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8149#issuecomment-471927034) sadly did not work for me.

I have some some policies. The default one requires the existence of a claim. But another policy requires that this claim does NOT exist. If the default one is applied on the controller, I can not apply the other one on the method. Instead of overriding my previous policy, the policies are all collected together and the first policy fails because the claim is not available.

A good example:

Startup:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // 99% of the methods require you to have this claim, so we set this as default.
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireClaim("UserId")
        .Build();

    options.AddPolicy("UnregisteredUsers",
        new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser() // You DO need to be authorized, but that does not mean you already have an account!
            .RequireAssertion(x => x.User.FindUserIdClaim() == null) // If you do not have a user ID, you can not access endpoints that require you to be registered until you have an ID
unregistered.
            .Build());

    // A more specific policy
    options.AddPolicy("Administrator",
        new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireRole(Roles.Administrator)
            .Build());
});
```

Controllers:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize] // You could also use MapControllers().RequireAuthorization() in Startup.cs instead of [Authorize]
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{

}

public class UsersController : BaseController
{

    // You can only access this endpoint IF you do not have an account.
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Policy = "UnregisteredUsers")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAccount()
    {
       // Code here
       return Ok();
    }
    

    // This one uses the default policy, just like many other policies
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsers()
    {
       // This would throw if unregistered users would access this endpoint because the claim is not set.
       var userId = User.GetUserIdClaim();
      
       // Other code here
       return Ok();      
    }
}
```

As you can see, if you were to try to create an account, the basecontroller would already deny you access because you do not have that claim. But I require the claim to NOT exist, so this is not a useful comment. Basically, my 2nd policy is more important than the first one.

I hope you guys can help me out!

---

*EDIT:*

Thanks to @King King I have been able to fix this.
Their answer works, but I needed to make some changes for some specific scenario's:

- The order is apparently [not guaranteed](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18961#issuecomment-590498307).
- The answer works when you want to "override" an existing policy by "turning it around". In this case, by default I require a user ID, but another policy requires that you DO not have it. *But* a scenario that is not supported out of the box is when you have a policy that does not care if you have user ID or not. I will post my FULL solution here but I am very grateful for @King King for his help!

```cs
// Note: Scope is REQUIRED!
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, UserIdClaimRequirementHandler>();

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // 99% of the methods require you to have this claim, so we set this as default.
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddRequirements(new UserIdClaimRequirement(UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustExist))
        .Build();

    options.AddPolicy("UnregisteredUsers",
        new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser() // You DO need to be authorized, but that does not mean you already have an account!
            .AddRequirements(new UserIdClaimRequirement(UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustNotExist)) // If you do not have a user ID, it means you are not in the database yet, which means you are unregistered.
            .Build());

    // Registed users and Unregistered users can access these endpoints, but they DO need to be authenticated.
    options.AddPolicy("AllUsers",
        new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddRequirements(new UserIdClaimRequirement(UserIdClaimSetting.IgnoreClaim))      
            .Build());

    // A more specific policy. This builds upon the default policy, so a user ID is required. Technically we could also omit the RequireAuthenticatedUser() call but I like that this is explicit.
    options.AddPolicy("Administrator",
        new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireRole(Roles.Administrator)
            .Build());
});
```

Requirement class:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Can be used to configure the requirement of the existence of the UserId claim.
/// Either it must exist, it must NOT exist or it does not matter. <br/><br/>
/// 
/// Please note: Order is not guaranteed with policies. <br/>
/// In the case when you use a <see cref="UserIdClaimSetting.IgnoreClaim"/> or <see cref="UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustNotExist"/> and the default policy uses a <see cref="UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustExist"/>,
/// the handler should prioritize the result of the <see cref="UserIdClaimSetting.IgnoreClaim"/> and <see cref="UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustNotExist"/> 
/// and just not evaluate <see cref="UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustExist"/> to prevent it returning 403 when that one runs last.
/// In order to do so, the handler MUST be registered as Scoped so it resets for the next reset.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This is quite a silly solution! 
/// The reason it is necessary is because policies are built on top of each other.
/// The default policy requires that the claim exists because this is true for 99% of the requests, 
/// so it makes sense to make this the default to prevent having to explicitly setup authorization on each endpoint. <br/><br/>
/// The "UnregisteredUsers" policy requires that it does NOT exist.<br/><br/>
/// The "AllUsers" policy does not care if it exists or not. 
/// Your first thought is probably that using this requirement would be unnecessary in that case,
/// but if this requirement is not used there, the default policy's requirement will require the existence of the claim which will break this policy.
/// </remarks>
public class UserIdClaimRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public UserIdClaimSetting Setting { get; }

    public UserIdClaimRequirement(UserIdClaimSetting setting)
    {
        Setting = setting;
    }
}

public enum UserIdClaimSetting
{
    /// <summary>
    /// If the claim does <b>not</b> exist, authorization will fail
    /// </summary>
    ClaimMustExist,
    /// <summary>
    /// If the claim exists, authorization will fail
    /// </summary>
    ClaimMustNotExist,
    /// <summary>
    /// It does not matter if the claim exists. Either way, authorization will succeed.
    /// </summary>
    IgnoreClaim
}
```

Requirement Handler:

```cs
public class UserIdClaimRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserIdClaimRequirement>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Order is not guaranteed with policies. 
    /// In the case when you use a <see cref="UserIdClaimSetting.IgnoreClaim"/> or <see cref="UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustNotExist"/> and the default policy uses a <see cref="UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustExist"/>,
    /// the handler should prioritize the result of the <see cref="UserIdClaimSetting.IgnoreClaim"/> and <see cref="UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustNotExist"/> 
    /// and just not evaluate <see cref="UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustExist"/> to prevent it returning 403 when that one runs last.
    /// In order to do so, the handler MUST be registered as Scoped so it resets for the next reset.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _policyHasAlreadySucceeded = false;

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserIdClaimRequirement requirement)
    {
        if(_policyHasAlreadySucceeded)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var hasUserId = context.User.FindFirst("UserId") != null;
        // If the claim must not exist but it does  -> FAIL
        // If the claim must exist but it does not  -> FAIL
        // If it doesn't matter if the claim exists -> SUCCEED
        if ((requirement.Setting == UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustNotExist && hasUserId) ||
            (requirement.Setting == UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustExist && !hasUserId) ||
            (requirement.Setting == UserIdClaimSetting.IgnoreClaim && false))
        {
            context.Fail();
        }
        else
        {
            // This requirement has succeeded!

            _policyHasAlreadySucceeded = requirement.Setting == UserIdClaimSetting.IgnoreClaim || requirement.Setting == UserIdClaimSetting.ClaimMustNotExist;

            // Also, if there are other policy requirements that use the UserId claim, just set them to SUCCEEDED because this requirement is more important than those.
            // Example: The default policy requires you to have a user id claim, while this requirement might be used by requiring the claim to NOT exist.
            // In order to make this work, we have to override the "require user id claim" requirement by telling it that it succeeded even though it did not!
            var otherUserIdClaimRequirements = context.Requirements.Where(e => e is UserIdClaimRequirement || e is ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement cu && cu.ClaimType == "UserId");
            foreach (var r in otherUserIdClaimRequirements)
            {
                context.Succeed(r);
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The authorization requirement handlers are ANDed. So if any failed, the whole will fail.
The authorization policies will be transformed into a set of authorization requirement handlers. Per my debugging, there are 2 authorization requirements transformed from the default policy (in your code) namely `DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement` (corresponding to `RequireAuthenticatedUser()`) and `ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement` with `ClaimType = "UserId"` (corresponding to `RequireClaim("UserId")`).

I've found myself one way to override the result (or simply skip, I'm not so sure about this) of the handlers that handle those 2 requirements. That is by implement a custom requirement handler in which you have access to the `AuthorizationHandlerContext` which exposes all the authorization requirements that need to be handled (of course including the 2 those I mentioned above). By calling `Succeed` on them, they seem to be ignored (from being handled again or simply skipped). We can add our second custom authorization requirement handler to verify that but it's not important at all (so I did not do it).

Here is how you build your custom policy (`UnregisteredUsers`) using a custom authorization requirement handler instead of basing on `RequireAssertion`:

```
//the custom requirement class which must implement IAuthorizationRequirement
public class NoUserIdClaimRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
//the corresponding handler
public class NoUserIdClaimRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<NoUserIdClaimRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, NoUserIdClaimRequirement requirement)
    {
        var hasUserId = context.User.FindFirst("UserId") != null;
        if (hasUserId)
        {
            context.Fail();                
        } else
        {
            //NOTE: if you're sure about the extremely high priority of this requirement 
            //(so we can discard/ignore all the other requirements), just remove the .Where for a shorter code
            foreach (var r in context.Requirements
                                     .Where(e => e is NoUserIdClaimRequirement ||
                                                 e is ClaimsAuthorizationRequirement cu && cu.ClaimType == "UserId"))
            {
                //mark all as succeeded
                context.Succeed(r); 
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

In the code above, I understand that the user still need to be authenticated so we don't call `Succeed` for `DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement`. If that's not true, you can include it in the filter above.

You need to register the authorization requirement handler type in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, NoUserIdClaimRequirementHandler>();
```

Now instead of using `RequireAssertion`, you need to build your custom policy like this:

```
options.AddPolicy("UnregisteredUsers",
                  x => x.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .AddRequirements(new NoUserIdClaimRequirement()));
```

I've tried a simple demo on my own, which works perfectly. But it may need some tweak from your own side. If any error occurs, please let me know. The code here is just to show the idea about a possible way to solve this issue. You can base on that to build a more complicated & general solution.

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your answer. I have used it and it successfully works,but there are some gotcha's that i had to write some code around. I will add them to my question for people to read and I will accept your answer!

Comment: @S.tenBrinke you're welcome, I'm glad it's helpful. I know your actual scenario may require a more complicated logic but as I said the answer here is just a proof of concept for a possible way to override the authorization policy. I've read the link in your question as well and the asp.net core team there decided not to provide any similar feature to support overriding the authorization filters (as some guys wished for there) because of some possible security issues (due to carelessness of using the feature). I agree with that and I think we should keep it simple when it comes to authorization